# Keep client connected to WebSocket in react native and express server

Tags: react-native, express, websocket

I have a react native application where i have two users using the app (customer and restaurant)
So on checkout I connect the customer to websocket on the express server and once the order is placed i send a message to the restaurant which is supposed to be connected to websocket all time.
However,  sometimes the restaurant is disconnected somehow, so I am trying to keep the restaurant connected, and if disconnected then reconnect again automatically.

In react native restaurant side implementation i have the following code :
this is `useWebSocketLite` hook to handle connection, send, receive messages and retry connection to server when closed:

```
function useWebSocketLite({ socketUrl, retry: defaultRetry = 3, retryInterval = 1000 }) {
    const [data, setData] = useState();
    const [send, setSend] = useState(() => () => undefined);
    const [retry, setRetry] = useState(defaultRetry);
    const [readyState, setReadyState] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const ws = new WebSocket(socketUrl);
        ws.onopen = () => {
            setReadyState(true);
            setSend(() => {
                return (data) => {
                    try {
                        const d = JSON.stringify(data);
                        ws.send(d);
                        return true;
                    } catch (err) {
                        return false;
                    }
                };
            });

            ws.onmessage = (event) => {
                const msg = formatMessage(event.data);
                setData({ message: msg, timestamp: getTimestamp() });
            };
        };

        ws.onclose = () => {
            setReadyState(false);
            if (retry > 0) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setRetry((retry) => retry - 1);
                }, retryInterval);
            }
        };
        return () => {
            ws.close();
        };
    }, [retry]);

    return { send, data, readyState };
}
```

So based on this, every-time the connection is closed, the connection will retry again.

Besides, when a restaurant launches the app the following code will be implemented:

```
const ws = useWebSocketLite({
    socketUrl: `wss://${url}/id=${user.user_id}&role=restaurant`
});
```

This useEffect to establish the connection:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (ws.readyState === true) {
            setConnectionOpen(true);
        }
    }, [ws.readyState]);
```

and this useEffect to handle incoming messages

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (ws.data) {
        const message = ws.data;
        //dispatch...
    }
}, [ws.data]);
```

**Express server implementation:**

This is the code where i handle socket connections and messages in express server:

```
var webSockets = {}
function setupWebSocket(server) {
    server.on('connection', (socket, req) => {

        if (req) {

            var clientId = req.url
            let regexReplace = /[\[\]/]/g
            let regex = /([^=#&]+)=([^?&#]*)/g,
                params = {},
                match;
            while ((match = regex.exec(clientId))) {
                params[decodeURIComponent(match[1]).replace(regexReplace, '')] = decodeURIComponent(match[2])
            }
            if (params.role === 'restaurant') {
                webSockets[params.id] = socket
            }
        }
        socket.on('message', data => {

            let sData = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data))
            let {id, data} = sData.data
            sendToClient(id, 'order', data)

        })


        socket.on('error', (err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
        socket.on('close', (code, req) => {
            var clientId = req.url
            let regexReplace = /[\[\]/]/g
            let regex = /([^=#&]+)=([^?&#]*)/g,
                params = {},
                match;
            while ((match = regex.exec(clientId))) {
                params[decodeURIComponent(match[1]).replace(regexReplace, '')] = decodeURIComponent(match[2])
            }

            if (params.role === 'restaurant') {
                delete webSockets[clientId]
                console.log(`${webSockets[clientId]} disconnected with code ${code} !`);
            }


        });
    });


    // sends a message to a specific client
    const sendToClient = (clientId, type, data = {}) => {
        const payload = { type, data }
        const messageToSend = JSON.stringify({ error: false, message: payload })

        if (webSockets[clientId]) {
            webSockets[clientId].send(messageToSend)
            console.log(`${clientId} client notified with this order`)

        } else {
            console.log(`${clientId} websocket client is not connected.`)

        }
    }


}
```

So most of the time I get `13 websocket client is not connected.` which means the restaurant has already been deleted from the webSockets object and its connection already closed.

Apologise for long question and hope someone can help me regarding this.

Comment: Can you exmplain to me why you have "return () => {
            ws.close();
        }; " right at the end of your useEffect ?

Comment: @AhmadMOUSSA I am doing ws.close to clean up as the best practice for useEffect to clean up when the component unmount. So you are suggesting me to not return ` ws.close();` ?

Answer (score 0):

*First of all, you should know that this **is not a good practice of websockets**, where you are forcing the client (the restaurant) to be connected.*

**Whatever**, at the current state of your code, there is an **illogical behavior**: at the end of the useEffect of your “useWebSocketLite” function, you are closing the socket connection:

```
return () => {
        ws.close();
    };
```

Knowing that the useEffect hook is called twice: after the first render of the component, and then after every change of the dependencies (the “retry” state in your case); Your code can be ridden like so: everytime the “retry” state changes, we will close the socket! So for me that is why you got the client disconnected.

Comment: I am doing `ws.close` to clean up as the best practice for useEffect to clean up when the component unmount. So you are suggesting me to not return  ` ws.close();` ?

Comment: no, not necessarily to delete the ws.close(), but to return into the two functions ws.onopen & ws.onclose... If you don't return, it will execute the ws.close() at the end of your function (put a console.log just before the ws.close and you will see that this line will be executed even if you do ws.onopen or ws.onclose..)